# Is this a valid function. Translating Haskell code to pure maths

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion, recursive-algorithms, programming

I am currently learning Haskell and I wrote a tail recusive function to find the sum of some list.

I wanted to try and write it out in pure maths, transalating as closely as I can what I did in Haskell to maths, instead of simply using sigma to express the summation.

I would like to know if what I wrote out makes any sense or is valid and if not what would I have to change about it.

Here is what I made:

$$ 
  f(A) = g(A,0) = \sum_{x\in A}x \\
  g(A,s) =
  \begin{cases} 
    s \quad &\text{if } A = \emptyset \\ 
    g(\{a_2,a_3,...,a_n\},a_1+s) \quad &\text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases} \\
  \text{where} \\
  A \subsetneq \mathbb Z \\
$$

Here's the Haskell code I'm trying to translate.

```
mySum :: [Int] -> Int
mySum n = mySum' (n) 0
    where
        mySum' (n) x | null n    = x
        mySum' (n:ns) x | otherwise = mySum' (ns) (n + x)
```

Thanks!

edit: added pattern matching to Haskell for improved readability. Also sightly changed math function to better resemble the Haskell code.

Comment: Your Haskell code is a bit odd. Why are you not pattern-matching on $n$?

Comment: oh shoot, I tired to do pattern matching at first but something wasn't working right then I forgot that was how I was going to do it, going to try and reimplement right now.

Comment: A more idiomatic order of arguments would be to define `mySum' : Int -> [Int] -> Int` and then simply define point-free `mySum = mySum' 0`. More idiomatic still would be to do no explicit recursion at all: `mySum = foldr (+) 0`.

Comment: It's rather unclear to me what you're asking; Haskell is as good a language as any for expressing actual methods for computing mathematical functions. I'm not aware of any better/more "mathematical" way to express an algorithm.

Comment: I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429634/foldl-is-tail-recursive-so-how-come-foldr-runs-faster-than-foldl by the way.

Comment: this was a question to a lab I previously did and the exercise specifically wanted a signature of <code>mySum :: [Int] -> Int<code>,  and for tail recursion to be implemented. I started doing math translation as an attempt to get better with math latex, and better understanding of functions, but I see your point, might change it to that.

Comment: @PatrickStevens oh that's a helpful link! I didn't really understand folder/foldl. That's interesting, I thought there might of been a more mathematical way to express it but perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: It's definitely worthwhile being able to convert recursive functions to tail-recursive ones; but it is sad not to use Haskell's partial evaluation when it's available!

Comment: c cannot be a fixed integer because then the recursion would fail.  Accordingly the use of c is unacceptably vague.

Comment: @WilliamElliot that crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure how to make it clear that it isn't a fixed integer. Suggestions?

Comment: `Int` allows $-1$, but $\Bbb{N}$ does not.  Nothing in the Haskell code restricts the sign of the head of `n`.  Perhaps you mean $\Bbb{Z}$ where you have $\Bbb{N}$ in the first two lines.

Comment: @EricTowers good point, I changed the set to Z

Comment: You want to recursively define a total function g:Pf(Z)×Z -> Z with the initial values g(A,0) = sum A and g(empty set,s) = s where Pf is the set of finite subsets and for consistency sum empty set = 0?  The problem is s jumps around.  How is g(A,1) produced?